Why are GCC and clang telling me that there's an unmatched left brace in my format string when using a custom type formatter?
I wanted to define a custom formatter for boost::system::error_code, but when there's any text preceding the replacement field braces compilation fails on both GCC and clang: https://godbolt.org/z/sn7xdz4MT
The formatter in question looks like this:
#include <iostream>
#include <format>
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>

template<>
struct std::formatter<boost::system::error_code, char> {
    constexpr auto parse(auto &ctx) {
        return ctx.end();
    }
    auto format(const boost::system::error_code &ec, auto &ctx) const
    {
        return std::format_to(ctx.out(), "{}", ec.message());
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::format("{}", boost::system::error_code()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::format(" {}", boost::system::error_code()) << std::endl;
}

Both GCC and clang report calling non-constexpr function called __unmatched_left_brace_in_format_string hence failing to construct the format string at compile time:
GCC:
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:22:29: error: call to consteval function 'std::basic_format_string<char, boost::system::error_code>(" {}")' is not a constant expression
   22 |     std::cout << std::format(" {}", boost::system::error_code()) << std::endl;
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from <source>:2:
<source>:22:29:   in 'constexpr' expansion of 'std::basic_format_string<char, boost::system::error_code>(" {}")'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/format:4208:19:   in 'constexpr' expansion of '__scanner.std::__format::_Checking_scanner<char, boost::system::error_code>::std::__format::_Scanner<char>.std::__format::_Scanner<char>::_M_scan()'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/format:3949:30:   in 'constexpr' expansion of '((std::__format::_Scanner<char>*)this)->std::__format::_Scanner<char>::_M_on_replacement_field()'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/format:4003:60: error: call to non-'constexpr' function 'void std::__format::__unmatched_left_brace_in_format_string()'
 4003 |           __format::__unmatched_left_brace_in_format_string();
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/format:203:3: note: 'void std::__format::__unmatched_left_brace_in_format_string()' declared here
  203 |   __unmatched_left_brace_in_format_string()
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Clang:
<source>:22:30: error: call to consteval function 'std::basic_format_string<char, boost::system::error_code>::basic_format_string<char[4]>' is not a constant expression
   22 |     std::cout << std::format(" {}", boost::system::error_code()) << std::endl;
      |                              ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/15.0.0/../../../../include/c++/15.0.0/format:4120:4: note: non-constexpr function '__unmatched_left_brace_in_format_string' cannot be used in a constant expression
 4120 |           __format::__unmatched_left_brace_in_format_string();
      |           ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/15.0.0/../../../../include/c++/15.0.0/format:4066:7: note: in call to 'this->_M_on_replacement_field()'
 4066 |                     _M_on_replacement_field();
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/15.0.0/../../../../include/c++/15.0.0/format:4377:2: note: in call to '__scanner._M_scan()'
 4377 |         __scanner._M_scan();
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:22:30: note: in call to 'basic_format_string<char[4]>(" {}")'
   22 |     std::cout << std::format(" {}", boost::system::error_code()) << std::endl;
      |                              ^~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/15.0.0/../../../../include/c++/15.0.0/format:209:3: note: declared here
  209 |   __unmatched_left_brace_in_format_string()
      |   ^

Is this a problem with my code?

please include the [mcve] and error message directly in the question. Godbolt links are nice additions but if possible all relevant information should be directly in the question.

Again, please include the error message(s) as text verbatim in your question.  In this case there are multiple error messages, the first of which you appear to have completely ignored.

The parse() function is not implemented correctly. You can directly inherit from std::formatter<std::string> and use its parse() function.

The problem is that your parse function isn't behaving as GCC/Clang want - It should point to the closing '}' in the parse context.  In your case, it's pointing to one after, which is consuming the '}', so the compiler is failing
GCC/Clang expect you to consume values from the parse context, and return the first unmatched character. I can't really explain why it allows the "{}" format, nor can I really confirm if their behavior is correct by the specification.
Replace the body of your parse function with
return ctx.begin();

Given your format function, you can also choose to inherit your formatter from the string formatter, as recommended by 康桓瑋 in the comments.
